# SQLAlchemy: Is it better (faster?) to commit small sessions or large ones?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For the task of writing/updating a large number of lines to a table in postgreSQL using the sqlalchemy ORM, would it be faster/ more efficient to commit at every row or to add all the rows to the session first before committing?

E.g.
(1)

```
for foo in bar:
    session.add(foo)
    session.commit()
```

or:
(2)

```
for foo in bar:
    session.add(foo)

session.commit()
```

I did a rough test by timing the running time of the python script for n = 20 rows and the results favored (1) by a very small margin, though I think that could just be the noise.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I did more researching an came across a probable answer on SQLAlchemy's mailing list on the Google groups. Credits go to Mr. Simon King for the following answer:

> I think the idea of processing the rows in chunks is to limit the 
>   memory usage of the Python process. Until you call session.flush(), 
>   all your modifications are held in memory. For small numbers of rows 
>   this isn't a problem, but for huge numbers, it might be.
>
> In practice, it may not actually make a difference for this example, 
>   because the default session configuration is to autoflush whenever you
>   call session.query().
>
> As to whether this is preferred over Table.update(), it really depends
>   on your use case. Table.update() will usually be faster, because all 
>   the work will be done by the database itself. If the changes you are 
>   trying to make can be expressed in SQL (ie. they don't have 
>   complicated dependencies or require outside information), and you are 
>   happy to resynchronise your session afterwards if necessary, then 
>   Table.update() is fine.
>
> Hope that helps,
>
> Simon